# Adding event to button programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add an event to a programmatically generated button like this:

```
Button activityButton = new Button();
activityButton.Click += new EventHandler(onChangeActivityFilter);
```

I'm getting the following exception in the 2nd line:

> Cannot implicit convert type `System.EventHandler` to `System.Windows.RoutedEventhandler`

The onChangeActivityFilter methode looks like this:

```
private void onChangeActivityFilter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use lambda functions

```
activityButton.Click += (sender, e) => 
{
    MessageBox.Show("the button was clicked");
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a instance of `RoutedEventHandler`:

```
activityButton.Click += new RoutedEventhandler(onChangeActivityFilter);
```

And also change the method signature:

```
private void onChangeActivityFilter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

RoutedEvents where introduced with WPF.